# Facing issue with row and column in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

As a beginner in Flutter, I am trying to achieve dynamic adjustment of the green widget on the top and bottom sides and the right widget part's top and bottom sides. Additionally, I am seeking guidance on how to solve the overflow issue shown in the image.

thanks in advance

[image: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF380.jpg)]

I have included my code below, and I have attempted various methods to achieve the desired design. However, I have not been successful in accomplishing it. Could someone provide me with a detailed explanation of how to achieve this design?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const IomHistory2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return history();
  }

  Widget history() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      child: Row(
        //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          leftContainer("1", Colors.green),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                rightContainer(
                    "Forgot to attendance punch, i was in the office from 8.30 to 6.20",
                    null,
                    false),
                rightContainer("23/01/2023-23/01/2023", Icons.date_range, true),
                rightContainer("08:30-18:20", Icons.access_time, true),
                rightContainer("Accepted", Icons.done, true),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget leftContainer(String totalDays, Color color) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16, left: 8, right: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.zero,
              topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
              bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(8.0))),
      child: Column(
        //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          customTextLeftContainer(totalDays),
          customTextLeftContainer("Day"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget rightContainer(String value, IconData? iconData, bool iconShowed) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          iconShowed ? Icon(size: 14, iconData) : Container(),
          customTextRightContainer(value, iconShowed)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget customTextLeftContainer(String value) {
    return Text(value,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Rubik', fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
  }

  Widget customTextRightContainer(String value, bool iconShowed) {
    return Container(
      margin: iconShowed
          ? const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8)
          : const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
      child: Text(
        value,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Rubik',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

***I want this***

[image]

Comment: Kindly add your code here for the same so that someone can help

Comment: Please share your desired UI Snippet

Comment: Can you share the desired ui design, because your requirements seems a bit blurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `Row` with `Intrinsic` Widget and use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`.

And use `Expanded` Widget where necessary.

**Output:**

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
  Widget history() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 32),
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            leftContainer("1", Colors.green),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  rightContainer(
                      "Forgot to attendance punch, i was in the office from 8.30 to 6.20",
                      null,
                      false),
                  rightContainer(
                      "23/01/2023-23/01/2023", Icons.date_range, true),
                  rightContainer("08:30-18:20", Icons.access_time, true),
                  rightContainer("Accepted", Icons.done, true),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget leftContainer(String totalDays, Color color) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16, left: 8, right: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.zero,
              topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
              bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(8.0))),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          customTextLeftContainer(totalDays),
          customTextLeftContainer("Day"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget rightContainer(String value, IconData? iconData, bool iconShowed) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          iconShowed ? Icon(size: 14, iconData) : Container(),
          Expanded(child: customTextRightContainer(value, iconShowed))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget customTextLeftContainer(String value) {
    return Text(value,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Rubik', fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
  }

  Widget customTextRightContainer(String value, bool iconShowed) {
    return Container(
      margin: iconShowed
          ? const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8)
          : const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
      child: Text(
        value,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Rubik',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```